NLTK throws FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Hey can anyone tell what is the reason of FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
I am running on Docker ecs fargate task and this throws error.
I have tried to build and run image on local it works fine but on ecs fargate this throws error.
Below is my docker file
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes build-essential python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev libpq-dev pkg-config\
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN groupadd -r runner && useradd -r -g runner runner

COPY requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r requirements/base.txt
COPY handler.py /
COPY document_generation /document_generation

RUN export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$(pwd)";

WORKDIR /

# Create a temporary directory and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /documents_api_tmp && chmod 777 -R /documents_api_tmp && chmod o+t -R /documents_api_tmp
ENV TMPDIR=/documents_api_tmp

# Debugging step: Check directory permissions and disk usage
RUN df -h \
    && du -sh /documents_api_tmp

USER runner

CMD ["python", "handler.py"]




Well that's really strange that it works locally but not on ECS/Fargate, since this particular aspect of the docker container should not be any different in those two environments. It does look like one thing your Dockerfile does is create a "temporary directory" at /documents_api_tmp. Could it be that your Python script needs some environment variable to tell it to use that as a temporary directory, and you are only seting that environment variable locally?
